# Display navbar on all pages except home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show two different navbars. One will be displayed, on all pages except home page, when you're logged in. While the other navbar will be displayed just on my landing page.

I am thinking that I will probably need to write an if statement.

```
If (current user is not logged in) or maybe (current user is viewing home page) do
<nav>Second navbar</nav>
else
<nav>First navbar</nav>
end
```

I am very new to rails, so I could be wrong. (And yes, I know that's not how to correctly write an if statement in Ruby)

Home page is located at:

home/index.html.erb

Answer (score 3):

I normally do following setup:

- create partial `shared/_nav_menu.html.erb`

inside partial I put logic like:

```
<% if current_user %>
  // nav bar for logged in user
<% else %>
 // nav bar for non logged in users
<% end %>
```

Then inside `application.html.erb` file I render the `partial` like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/_nav_menu' if show_menu? %>
```

Inside my `application_controller` I put logic like this:

```
def show_menu?
  true
end

helper method: show_menu?
```

If I don't want to show the menu for `static_pages` then inside `static_pages_controller` I overwrite `show_menu?` method to return `false`.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def show_menu? 
    false
  end

  helper_method: show_menu?
end
```

You don't have to use exactly this setup but I like this setup because my `nav menu` logic is kept seperate in partial. All logic required to `nav menu` lives in this file.

This approach don't bloat my `application.html.erb` file with lots of `if..else`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of two menus, but leaving yourself open to more, I would use a similar-but-slightly-different approach than Reboot's answer.

In the layout:

```
<%= render :partial => @nav_bar_partial %>
```

Then in my application controller, define the default nav:

```
def standard_nav
  @nav_bar_partial = "path/to/standard/nav/partial"
end
```

From there, you can override that nav partial any time you need to (with any partial you want) from your controller

```
@nav_bar_partial = "path/to/new/nav/partial" if condition_that_requires_a_different_nav
```

That way, you have a little more flexibility. If for some reason you want to add a third nav bar for some other condition, you can just override the partial elsewhere without changing any of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare two layouts, one for the landing page and another for rest of the pages. Take a look at the official documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.